# Problem with membership contribution page

Tags: civimember

In civimember, I'm setting up a contribution page. The help for the "display membership fee" field says:
"If the page 'Separate Membership Payment' is NOT enabled AND the Contribution Amount is enabled so that user's can opt to give more than the minimum membership fee - then the display looks like this:

General Membership (contribute at least $100.00 to be eligible for this membership)"

When I try this I only get the minimum membership fee with an additional form for people to list an amount. What am I missing? I'd like to have the (contribute at least... line with a form where the person can list the total they'd like to pledge rather than adding the amount to the minimum membership fee.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest the following but found that a Price Field for memberships that is set to Text / Numeric Quantity doesn't allow one to set the Membership type - odd - am digging further but will leave the recipe here for now

Turn off Contribution Amount on the Amounts tab.

Create a Price Set set up for Membership and with Min Amount set to $100, make a Price Field of type Text / Numeric Quantity with 1.00 as the unit.

Turn off Display Amount.

On the membership tab of the Contribution Page select Price Set created above

You should then have a field where you can enter an amount and if it is not above the minimum required will get an outcome like this.

[image]